# Surface color only changes after window is closed in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I’m new to Pygame and have watched a tutorial on a few games. The problem I’m having is that the surface color doesn’t change unless I close the window. I’ve seen many people put their fill underneath in the game loop and the background color immediately changes, but in my case it remains black until I hit the close button. It then changes color and exits.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
blue=(0,0,255)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('virus')
icon= pygame.image.load('virus-face.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
screen.fill(blue)

pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html).
`screen.fill(blue)` and `screen.fill(blue)` have to be done in the application loop:

```py
running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running=False

    screen.fill(blue)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same issue all through yesterday and non of the answers given here worked for me so I started playing around with my code until it worked. Here's what my code looks like.

```
                 import pygame
                 pygame.init()

                 screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600 ))

                 running = True
                 while running:

                      screen.fill((255, 255, 0))
                      pygame.display.update()

                      for event in pygame.event.get():
                            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                running = False 

                 pygame.quit()
```